# Crossfilter filters not filtering (dc.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to use filters in crossfilter, but nope.

[Here's the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/liwiru/8/edit)

Here's the most relevant code:

```
var userDimension = data.dimension(function(d) {return d.user;}).filter(['John', 'Paul']);
var totalSalesByUser = userDimension.group();
var pieChartUserSales = dc.pieChart("#pie-chart-sales-by-user");
pieChartUserSales
  .width(150).height(150)
  .dimension(userDimension)
  .group(totalSalesByUser); 

dc.renderAll();
```

The pie chart looks the same with and without the filter, but the effect I'm looking for is narrowing it down to the items where John or Paul is the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crossfilter filters don't apply to groups defined on the same dimension as the filter. Create a second dimension and filter on that.

Here's an updated example. Also note that the filter you defined doesn't do what you probably meant it to do, so I changed that to a function that filters to only Paul and John: http://jsbin.com/yugakire/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the updated jsbin, that solves my problem beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out crossfilter doesn't apply the filter to the dimension you put the filter on.  It applies it to *everything* *else*.

This makes sense after you think about it for a long long time.

Comment: Yup. Not intuitive, but it's exactly the right design decision for filtering on coordinated views.

Comment: @Jeffrey Can you explain more in details?

Comment: After I made the comment, I looked at my own chart (that takes in crossfilter object). It does make some sense, e.g. I have a chart A that shows number of book sales for each month of 2017 (using time dimension then group), second chart B shows total sales for different books. Suppose now I want to know the total sales between certain month, then I filter on the time dimension. B would change accordingly, but A does not necessarily need to change (since all the information is already there). But if I need to make the chart nicer and clear, then will create a time dimension copy to filter on.