# Filter Crossfilter dimension by date

Tags: javascript, json, date, crossfilter

How does one filter a range of dates using Crossfilter? The below does not work when I know for a fact records exist between that time period.

```
Var myDimension = CrossFilterObj.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.insertDate) });

myDimension.filterRange([new Date('December 30, 2014'), new Date('January 1, 2014')]);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, swapped December date with January date and it works.

Comment: Oh haha, I feel like I make that mistake all the time.

Comment: @Mr.White I'm also trying to filter on a dates dimenstion, but after running `myDimension.filterRange([new Date('December 30, 2014'), new Date('January 1, 2014')]);` the data did not change at all. Have you experienced this?

Comment: solved it, I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171662/crossfilter-filters-not-filtering-dc-js), so I was filtering the date on the date dimension itself. Group won't apply for such case, I need to make a separate dimension to filter on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because of the primitive type restriction of `dimension` you need to use `valueOf` on `Date` or simply `getTime()`

```
var myDimension = 
  CrossFilterObj.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.insertDate).getTime() })

myDimension.filterRange([
  new Date('December 30, 2014').getTime(), new Date('January 1, 2014').getTime()
])
```